# What works with Vanilla Ender Chests in FTB?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

In FTB, lots of items interact with chests, such as Miners. Which, if any, of these items also work with vanilla Ender Chests?

Or conversely, which items **do not** work with vanilla Ender Chests? Whichever answer is smaller would be best.

Comment: Anything that would work with a chest should also work with an Ender Chest. As far as I know, the only difference in behavior in relation to items is their shared inventory.

Comment: supposedly hoppers dont work with ender chests....

Comment: Quick question: Vanilla or EnderStorage (mod) Ender Chests? I assumed EnderStorage because FTB.

Comment: Vanilla Ender Chests, I'm running Tech World, which doesn't include EnderStorage

Comment: **Tesseracts!**

Comment: most item transport systems **don't** work with vanilla enderchests (it's not a IInventory), I think there is maybe one mod that uses that inventory

Comment: But EnderStorage chests DO work? If so I'll install that...

Comment: I don't play FTB, but I kind of expect the answer will be “None of them”, because the thing about vanilla Ender Chests is that _they are completely non-specific_: they show the inventory belonging to _whoever is looking at them_, so a machine can't know whose ender-chest-inventory to use unless the machine itself is player-specific.

Comment: Yeah, the mod-added chests are a regular inventory and work with pipes and tubes. They're great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been said in the comments, the Vanilla Ender Chest can't be used by machines as each chest essentially links to a part of the players inventory. The tubes and pipes and what not won't be able to use the chest as they're not a real player (some mods fake players for certain actions, like ComputerCraft Turtles placing things or RedPower 2 deployers... deploying.

A [bugreport](https://github.com/BuildCraft/BuildCraft/issues/315) has been added for BuildCraft (transport pipes) for this issue, but the report was closed saying this is not fixable due to the way Vanilla Ender Chests work, and the same problem would happen for all other mods.